# Return Channel Earnings from YouTube API

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-analytics-api

I am trying to retrieve earnings from a channel in my CMS using the YouTube API. When I execute my query the response only contains the metrics datatype and not the actual value.  How do I return the earnings from the API?

```
stdClass Object (
    [kind] => youtubeAnalytics#resultTable [columnHeaders] => Array (
        [0] => stdClass Object (
            [name] => earnings [columnType] => METRIC [dataType] => FLOAT
        )
        [1] => stdClass Object (
            [name] => grossRevenue [columnType] => METRIC [dataType] => FLOAT
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you getting the metrics from a [Content owner report](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/content_owner_reports)? To run a content owner report, make sure that you're authenticated as your YouTube CMS account, then set `ids=contentOwner==CMS_ID` and `filters=channel==CHANNEL_ID` or `filters=video==VIDEO_ID`.